# How to show a div when another div is scrolled out of DOM

Tags: html, jquery, scroll, scrolltop

I have a fixed div(logo-fixed) that appears when scrolling 1070px from Top, but I don't want that, I like the div to appear when I scroll 50 pixels after another div(headerclass)

How can this be achieved?

9.

this is the code

```js
(function($) {
$(".logo-fixed").css({"visibility": "hidden"});
    $(document).scroll(function () {
        var y = $(this).scrollTop();
 if (y > 1070) {
$(".logo-fixed").css({"visibility": "visible"});
            $('.logo-fixed').fadeIn(200);
        } else {
            $('.logo-fixed').hide(0);
        }
    });
})( jQuery );
```

```css
.headerclass {
    position:sticky;
        top:0;
    z-index:600;
}
.logo-fixed {
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:224px;
    height:120px;
    z-index:1000;
    background: url("#");
        background-position: center center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: contain;   
}
```

```html
<div class="headerclass"></div>
<div class="logo-fixed"></div>
```

Comment: You can't scroll something out of the DOM. Out of the viewport, sure, but that's still in the DOM.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I meant viewport

Answer (score 0):

You can get the position of the `headerclass` element with `$(.headerclass').scrollTop()` and then compare that to `y` in your conditional, instead of `1070`.

Example:

`if (y > 1070) {`

gets replaced with

`if (y > $(.headerclass').scrollTop() + 50 )`